# I can serve a brand new Jekyll site, but I can't build it

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

Basically, when I make a *brand new jekyll site* I can go in to the directory and do `bundle exec jekyll serve` and see the proper site at 127.0.0.1:4000, but when I do `bundle exec jekyll build` I get a broken index.html that when opened looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpHnD.png)

The other odd thing is that if I change the url: and baser: in my _config.yml to a website I've previously made and hosted, then it works fine.

I think I've messed something up with my ruby install (macOS Mojave), or previously figured out a way around this problem that I no longer remember so those previous sites url and baseurl work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be pleased to know that there's nothing wrong with your Ruby installation or the Jekyll version itself if `bundle exec jekyll serve` returns results as expected.

The sites generated by Jekyll are meant to be used with a server. That's the very reason the `jekyll serve` command exists.
`jekyll serve` first builds your site and then serves it on the browser via the WEBrick webserver.

Running `bundle exec jekyll build` will give you a production-ready site (in the `_site` directory by default). But it has to be hosted somewhere like GitHub Pages or Netlify or CloudCannon before you can *navigate* through the site.

For local browsing, `bundle exec jekyll serve` is the way.

Comment: I was thinking this, but I've certainly made standalone .html files that I was able to view without a server running, but I suppose that was because they were standalone files... I also mistakenly thought I had *built* a jekyll site and ran it without having a server running... I was clearly wrong.

Comment: Technically, the .html files generated by Jekyll are not that different from your standalone files. The sole difference is that Jekyll's HTML files link to *each other and local assets* with URLs with a leading slash. i.e. for example, they would look for `/assets/css/styles.css` instead of `assets/css/styles.css`..